# Mixture Modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I would like to know if it is possible to create a mixture using several single gases (using Modelica Library). If yes is there any document explaining this procedure ? Thank you very much for you answer

Comment: There are some mixtures of ideal gases available in the MSL, see `Modelica.Media.IdealGases.MixutreGases`, sufficient for e.g. flue gas modelling.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is a simple example to roll your own gas mixture (i*deal)

```
   package MyGas   "Specific ideal Gas Mixture"

   import Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa;
   import Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData ;
   import Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData;

   extends MixtureGasNasa (
           data = {SingleGasesData.N2, 
                   SingleGasesData.O2,
                   SingleGasesData.CO2},
           fluidConstants = {FluidData.N2,
                             FluidData.O2, 
                             FluidData.CO2}, 
           substanceNames = {"Nitrogen", "Oxygen", "CarbonDioxide"},
           reference_X = {0.768, 0.232, 0}
  ); //end of Extending MixtureGasNasa

 end MyGas;
```